# Нахождения всех подматриц

Tags: алгоритм, матрицы, комбинаторика

Как перебрать все подматрицы? Подматрицей называется часть матрицы, полученная вычеркиванием какого-либо количества строк, и(или) какого-либо количества столбцов. Для примера матрица:

```
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35
```

Подматрица:

```
12 13 15
22 23 25
27 28 30
```

При попытках написать алгоритм получается очень много вложенных циклов. Какой алгоритм можно использовать?

Comment: вычёркиваться могут только крайние или любые строки/столбцы?

Comment: Любые строки и любые столбцы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35171721/5741205

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если размер не слишком большой (скажем, до 32x32 :)), обозначим вычеркнутую строку/столбец 0, оставленную - 1. Тогда любой набор вычеркиваний из набора N столбцов описывается числом от 0 до 2<sup>N</sup>. То же и для строк.

Так что получаем два цикла - по строкам и по столбцам, ну, а внутри надо просто аккуратно разобраться, какие строки и столбцы остаются и записать получающуюся матрицу.

Для показанного вами варианта имеется 1024 подматрицы - от пустой до полной матрицы.